# Spring Security : Who passes the AuthenticationManagerBuilder to the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter configure method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

So I am studying Spring Security for a implementation. I came across a piece of code I cannot get my head around. So as per documentation the following method needs to be overridden when we want to customize the AuthenticationManager used by Spring.

`protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws java.lang.Exception`

My question is who is calling this method and passing the **AuthenticationManagerBuilder** instance here.
The working examples I see do not create/expose any **AuthenticationManagerBuilder** bean.

Also , i see the following in the documentation,

> protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager()
>                                                  throws java.lang.Exception Gets the AuthenticationManager to use.
>
> The default
>   strategy is if configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder) method is
>   overridden to use the AuthenticationManagerBuilder that was passed in.
>   Otherwise, autowire the AuthenticationManager by type.

The overridden method is a void method and probably that is why I am getting confused more w.r.t what it is doing/should be doing.

Any help/pointers are highly appreciated. I know it works I just cant seem to figure out how.
Much thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming following is the code you came across

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(MyAuthenticationProvider);
    }
}
```

Note that

1. The [WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html) provides a convenient base
   class for creating a [WebSecurityConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/WebSecurityConfigurer.html) instance.
2. The WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implementation is a
   [Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) as it is annotated with @EnableWebSecurity

Here

@EnableWebSecurity is meta-annotated with @EnableGlobalAuthentication

```
@Retention(value=RUNTIME)
 @Target(value=TYPE)
 @Documented
 @Import(value={WebSecurityConfiguration.class,org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.SpringWebMvcImportSelector.class,org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ImportSelector.class})
 @EnableGlobalAuthentication
 @Configuration
public @interface EnableWebSecurity
```

and @EnableGlobalAuthentication imports AuthenticationConfiguration

```
@Retention(value=RUNTIME)
 @Target(value=TYPE)
 @Documented
 @Import(value=AuthenticationConfiguration.class)
 @Configuration
public @interface EnableGlobalAuthentication
```

AuthenticationConfiguration has the following piece of code that registers AuthenticationManagerBuilder as a bean

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder(
            ObjectPostProcessor<Object> objectPostProcessor, ApplicationContext context) {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. This would have taken me much time and aggravation to figure out.